# simplescreenrecorder: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, sudo, chmod, chown

I'd like to use a location different to my home directory for recording  videos using SimpleScreenRecorder. However, when I "Browse..." File -> Save as: I get the following error message:

```
Could not read the contents of media
Error opening directory '/media': Permission denied
```

as soon as I browse into '/media' folder.

I already changed ownership of the folder from root to $USER, still the same. When I try to launch the application from the terminal using `sudo` or `gksudo` it fails to launch the application with

**sudo**

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
```

**gksudo**

```
(gksudo:19480): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
No protocol specified
simplescreenrecorder: cannot connect to X server :0
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Everything works fine when I use my $HOME directory. I'd prefer to use the application without root permissions if possible.

For testing only I temporarily set /media permissions to 777 and it still did not work.

Please advice, thank you

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version and flavour? Are you by any chance in a Wayland session by any chance? What is the output of the following command in Terminal: `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`?

Comment: it is Ubuntu 16.04. I already tried `sudo chown $USER:$USER /media` but since @kukulo suggested I run again with `-R`. Took a while but no difference. 

`$XDG_SESSION_TYPE` is `x11`. I don't use wayland sessions AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `chown` command:

```
sudo chown username:username -R /media/
```

Replace `username` with your `username`.

Comment: For details see man chown.